# 90th percentile response time in non gui mode

Tags: jmeter

I have run jmeter in non gui mode and saved the .jtl file. when I open the .jtl file Aggregate report listener, 90th percentile and max response times are same. How do i get the correct 90th percentile response times in non gui mode.

Comment: how much is the user load ?

Answer (score 0):

The obtained result may be correct. It depends on the response time values in the jtl file.

Consider the response time values:

```
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  22  22  22  22
```

For above values both 90th percentile and max is 22.
You may check with higher no. of users.